# could someone please explain me why Spring Mvc says Request processing failed and throws null pointer exception

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Basically, i have a `users` table and I am trying to do some basic login authentication of form, by making use of getters from Users pojo class. It throws null pointer exception.

Here I have a jquery which packs the data and sends it to the controller which handles userlogin:

```
$.ajax({// defining the below function as ajax responsive//
        url:'userlogin', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
        type:'POST',
        data:{user_email:email,user_password:pass},// function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
        success: function(response){// if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
                alert(response.message);
                            }               
    });
```

And here is the controller that handles that url:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/userlogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView validateuser(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result) {


    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView view =new ModelAndView("users");
        return view;
    }

    boolean userExists = loginService.checkLogin(loginForm.getUser_email(),loginForm.getUser_password());
    if(userExists){
        ModelAndView view =new ModelAndView("user_loginsuccess");
         return view;
    }else{
        ModelAndView view =new ModelAndView("users");
         return view;
    }
}
```

Here `loginform` is pojo class I created just to set and get the logincredentials (user_name and user_password). I also have created two interface api's "LoginDao and Login Service under `loginapi` package and implemented them under the package `loginimpl`.

The implementation of those interfaces is as follows:

```
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{

 @Autowired
 private LoginDao loginDAO;

   public void setLoginDAO(LoginDao loginDAO) {
          this.loginDAO = loginDAO;
   }

   public boolean checkLogin(String user_email, String user_password){
          System.out.println("In Service class...Check Login");
          return loginDAO.checkLogin(user_email, user_password);
   }
}

@Repository("loginDAO")
public class LoginDaoImpl implements LoginDao{

   @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
   protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
          this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }

   protected Session getSession(){
          return sessionFactory.openSession();
   }

   public boolean checkLogin(String user_email, String user_password){
        System.out.println("In Check login");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        boolean userFound = false;
        //Query using Hibernate Query Language
        String SQL_QUERY =" from Users as o where o.user_email=? and o.user_password=?";
        Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
        query.setParameter(0,user_email);
        query.setParameter(1,user_password);
        List list = query.list();

        if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
            userFound= true;
        }

        session.close();
        return userFound;              
   }
}
```

Could anyone please explain why I am getting null pointer exception? Is there any bug or have I done anything wrong? What is spring servlet trying to convey?

I'm really stuck with this code for many days, would really appreciate if someone takes interest looks in the code and knock my head about what I'm doing wrong, Thank you!

Comment: Add the exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not add your exception stacktrace,I am not sure if it can solve your problem,but according to your problem,you are missing `@Service` for `LoginServiceImpl`

You will get NullPointerException for `private LoginDao loginDAO`

```
@Service //need to add @service here
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{

 @Autowired
 private LoginDao loginDAO;//if not add @service,this line of code will throw NullPointerException

   public void setLoginDAO(LoginDao loginDAO) {
          this.loginDAO = loginDAO;
   }

   public boolean checkLogin(String user_email, String user_password){
          System.out.println("In Service class...Check Login");
          return loginDAO.checkLogin(user_email, user_password);
   }
}
```